# HTML form input to Javascript var to document.write

Tags: javascript, html, input, var, document.write

Here's the code I've got at the moment. It isn't working at all. I want to type a word into the input. When the form is submitted, the input value becomes the Javascript variable "germsearch". Then document.write the whole page so that it has those six frames (the src of five of which contains the variable "germsearch"). Basically, the idea is you search one term and it loads five frames searching in different dictionaries (keeping a sixth frame on top to keep the search box).

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function run() {
     var germsearch = document.getElementById("german").value;
     document.write("<html><head><title>GERMANICVS</title></head>
          <frameset rows=\"10%, 90%\">
            <frame src=\"searchbox.html\">
            <frameset cols=\"20%, 20%, 20%, 20%, 20%\">
              <frame src=\"http://de-is.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\">
              <frame src=\"http://de-sv.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\">
              <frame src=\"http://de-nl.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\">
              <frame src=\"http://de-no.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\">
              <frame src=\"http://de-da.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\">
            </frameset>
          </frameset></html>"); }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form onSumbit="run()">
  <input type="text" id="german" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="GERMANIFY">
</form>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance,
Lloyd

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<form onSumbit="run()">
```

to

```
<form onSubmit="run()">
```

Also, change your `document.write` to

```
document.write('<html><head><title>GERMANICVS</title></head><frameset rows=\"10%, 90%\"><frame src=\"searchbox.html\"><frameset cols=\"20%, 20%, 20%, 20%, 20%\"><frame src=\"http://de-is.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\"><frame src=\"http://de-sv.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\"><frame src=\"http://de-nl.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\"><frame src=\"http://de-no.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\"><frame src=\"http://de-da.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\"></frameset></frameset></html>');
```

(single-line) Either that or use backslashes before a newline.

Comment: Great thanks, I just wasted too much time over a typo... One more little question, that "searchbox.html" is the page this code is written in (so the seachbox page reloads itself in the top frame). But when you try to use it a second time, the document.write only rewrites that top frame. How can I make it overwrite the entire page again?

Comment: @dlph You can try `document.body.outerHTML=''` before your `document.write()`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working either unfortunately. But it doesn't matter a great deal, it's just a casual page for my own use. Thanks a lot for your help anyway.

Comment: @dlph Your welcome. I hope you solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your answer and it displays what you are trying to do
Firstly i changed your form because using the document.getElementByID to get a value feels wrong to me when you could use a document.forms
Also i had a "button" tag used instead of the normal "submit" button and everything works like you want it to work.

Hope this helps :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      function run() {
         var germsearch = document.forms["myForm"]["german"].value;
         alert(germsearch);
         document.write('<html><head><title>GERMANICVS</title></head><frameset rows=\"10%, 90%\"><frame src=\"searchbox.html\"><frameset cols=\"20%, 20%, 20%, 20%, 20%\"><frame src=\"http://de-is.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\"><frame src=\"http://de-sv.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\"><frame src=\"http://de-nl.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\"><frame src=\"http://de-no.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\"><frame src=\"http://de-da.pocket.dict.cc/?s=" +germsearch+ "\"></frameset></frameset></html>'); }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="myForm" >
      <input type="text" name="german">
      <button type="button" onclick="run()">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Ah that's good thanks. I never explicitly learnt any javascript so I didn't even know 'forms' was a thing (the type of 'thing' that probably has its own name). One point about the button/submit - I used onSubmit rather than onClick so that you can use the enter key to submit the form and you don't have click the button

Comment: I experimented with the submit button normally as well, and when i clicked the submit button, it wouldn't call the "run" function so i went on to make an actual button and label it submit, so it actually works, and i think using enter would work here too but i never checked :)